# Add whiteboard feature to TokBox Webrtc session

Tags: javascript, java, webrtc, opentok, tokbox

I have a working webrtc session working with a JSP (built with tokbox JS).Now i want to add the Shared Whiteboard feature to this session.I checked tokbox docs, there is nothing mentioned w.r.t whiteboard. there is a project at https://github.com/aullman/opentok-meet ,which has Whiteboard feature also (among other stunning features).
However i am not able to figure out, how to use this code ,js etc , to create a whiteboard feature. has anyone implemented this and point me to right direction.

Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The code for the whiteboard in that application is available as a separate project here: https://github.com/aullman/opentok-whiteboard

It has some brief instructions in the README, but in short it uses Angular.js and defines a new `ot-whiteboard` directive.

Comment: I checked this.Does this mean i have to use opentok-angular to write the whole webrtc session? because my otherwise Plain JS coded webrtc page doesnt work/integrate with this angular whiteboard.? Do you have any idea

Comment: @zee you can use plain JS and create the whiteboard functionality, but the whiteboard itself is not provided by TokBox or the OpenTok platform. you should just be using the `session.signal()` API to send data between browsers, but your own implementation of the whiteboard would be different.